# Python: how to transform a string which carries the filename into a readable filename?

Tags: python, loops, file-handling

I would like to loop through files into a directory, make something on these files and then for each file write out the result. 
But my files can't be read because python interprets file names as string objects and not a readable file. 
Is there a way to avoid this?

```
import re
import os


def create_filename_for_fileout (f1):
        fileout_n = f1.replace("TT", "out")
        fileout = "C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\FSC_Treetag\\out\\"+str(fileout_n)
        return fileout

for file_in in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\KP\\Desktop\\FSC_Treetag'):
    filename = str(file_in)
    file_out = create_filename_for_fileout(filename)

    open(file_in, 'r')
    open(file_out, 'w')


    content_file = file_in.readlines()
    for ln in content_file:
        regex = re.compile('(.*\t(ADJ|ADV|NOM|VER:cond|VER:futu|VER:impe|VER:impf|VER:infi|VER:pper|VER:pres|VER:pres|VER:simp|VER:subi|VER:subp)\t(.*))')
        res = regex.search(ln)
        if res:
         # categ = res.group(2)
           lemme = res.group(3)
           file_out.write(str(lemme)+"\n")

    file_out.close()    
    file_in.close()
```

Result:

```
 content_file = file_in.readlines()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "python interprets file names as string objects and not a readable file"?

Comment: @DavidZ  
`content_file = file_in.readlines()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
>>> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning your `open` to any variable to use.

```
# Change
open(file_in, 'r')
open(file_out, 'w')
# to
input_file = open(file_in, 'r')
output_file = open(file_out, 'w')

for ln in input_file:
    # do your processing
    if res:
        lemme = res.group(3)
        output_file.write(str(lemme) + "\n")
```

Comment: it works ! Why is it necessary to assign a variable in this case?

Comment: Your variables `file_in` and `file_out` are just strings of the name of the file, and not a file handler themselves. So when you open the file, it returns a `file` object and does not alter the filename variable to be a `file` object. Which is why you need to assign the returned file object from the open function to a variable that you will then be using.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the `open` functions to the respective `handlers` (`open` is returning an object of the file type).

```
filename = str(file_in)
file_out = create_filename_for_fileout(filename)

open(file_in, 'r')
open(file_out, 'w')
```

Should be:

```
file_out = open(create_filename_for_fileout(file_in), 'w')
file_in = open(file_in, 'r')
```

**NOTE**: for clarity sake it's a good idea to use another pointer for the **infile** `handler`.

Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
>
> ```
> Open a file, returning an object of the file type described in section File Objects. If the file cannot be opened, IOError is raised.
> ```